# Keep letter from letter range regex using sed?

Tags: regex, sed, backreference

I am using:

```
cat this_file | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n[a-z]/ [a-z]/g' > that_file
```

Sample text:

```
However the text \n
looks like this when it replaces the newline.\n
```

Output:

```
However the text [a-z]ooks like this when it replaces the newline.\n
```

What is this called? Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the pattern, `[a-z]` denotes a character class.  Within the replacement, it is substituted *as is*.  You need to use a backreference:

```
cat this_file | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\([a-z]\)/ \1/g' > that_file
```

Moreover, you could avoid useless use of cat:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\([a-z]\)/ \1/g' this_file > that_file
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks I wasn't aware of the backreference. Worked like a charm.